# How to count distinct values in SQL under different conditions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have a data that looks as below. I would like to count total number of products and create a table that summarize the count for different date range. Please see diagram below as an example. Here the quay I have:

```
SELECT( 
SELECT Count(DISTINCT Product) FROM Table1 WHERE  Date BETWEEN '01/01/2017 AND 
'01/15/2017,
SELECT Count(DISTINCT Product) FROM Table1 WHERE  Date BETWEEN '01/16/2017 AND 
'01/31/2017,    
);
```

But I get an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near ','
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
SELECT  
(SELECT Count(DISTINCT Product) FROM Table1 WHERE  Date BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND 
'01/15/2017'),
(SELECT Count(DISTINCT Product) FROM Table1 WHERE  Date BETWEEN '01/16/2017' AND 
'01/31/2017')    
;
```

You have a few syntax errors in your SQL:

- when using the BETWEEN statement, you must only put quotes around
  each date. Don't include the AND in the quotes.
- You need to put brackets around each of the inner SELECTS.
- There is an extra comma at the end (before the closing bracket)

However, this query will not return values of 5 and 2, because you are specifying DISTINCT in each SELECT. That will give you only 3 and 2 because there are only 3 distinct values for Product (A/D/E) returned from the first query. Remove the distinct if you want the number of rows.

Finally, I recommend that you use the YYYY-MM-DD syntax when using date literals in your SQL. This removes any ambiguity about what is the date and the month. For example, 1/4/2017 could be 4 Jan or 1 April, depending on how your SQL Server was configured. If you specify 2017-04-01, then this will always be interpreted as 1 April, and 2017-01-04 will always be 4 Jan.

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
    SELECT 
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Product) FROM yourtable T1 WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/15/2017') C1,
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Product) FROM yourtable T2 WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/16/2017' AND '01/31/201') C2
```

Outputs: 3 | 2

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable T1 WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/15/2017') C1,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable T2 WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/16/2017' AND '01/31/201') C2
```

Outputs : 5 | 2

Answer (score 0):

If the last code doesn't work you need to use Convert and Cast:

```
Declare @tb table(product  varchar(50),[Date] date)
insert into @tb

select 'A' as Product, cast(substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/1/2017' as date),110),7,4) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/1/2017' as date),110),1,2) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/1/2017' as date),110),4,2) as date) as [Date] union all

select 'A' as Product, cast(substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/1/2017' as date),110),7,4) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/1/2017' as date),110),1,2) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/1/2017' as date),110),4,2)as date) as [Date] union all

select 'D' as Product, cast(substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/5/2017' as date),110),7,4) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/5/2017' as date),110),1,2) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/5/2017' as date),110),4,2) as date) as [Date] union all

select 'E' as Product, cast(substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/6/2017' as date),110),7,4) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/6/2017' as date),110),1,2) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/6/2017' as date),110),4,2)as date) as [Date] union all


select 'E' as Product, cast(substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/10/2017' as date),110),7,4) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/10/2017' as date),110),1,2) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/10/2017' as date),110),4,2)as date) as [Date] union all


select 'D' as Product, cast(substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/25/2017' as date),110),7,4) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/25/2017' as date),110),1,2) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/25/2017' as date),110),4,2)as date) as [Date] union all


select 'A' as Product, cast(substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/30/2017' as date),110),7,4) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/30/2017' as date),110),1,2) + '-' +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast('1/30/2017' as date),110),4,2)as date) as [Date]

--Copy from here
select acnt as 'Count(01/01/2017-01/15/2017)',bcnt as 'Count(01/16/2017-01/31/2017)' from
(select count(1)   as acnt from @tb where [Date] BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/15/2017') as a
left join
(select count(1)   as bcnt from @tb where [Date]  BETWEEN '01/16/2017' AND '01/31/2017') as b
On a.acnt != b.bcnt or a.acnt = b.bcnt
```

Comment: it's is detailed but if you need the real query just copy the last code.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE(Product ,[Date])
As
(
SELECT 'A','1/1/2017'  Union all
SELECT 'A','1/1/2017'  Union all
SELECT 'D','1/5/2017'  Union all
SELECT 'E','1/6/2017'  Union all
SELECT 'E','1/10/2017' Union all
SELECT 'D','1/25/2017' Union all
SELECT 'A','1/30/2017'
)
SELECT SUM([Count Of between '1/1/2017' AND '1/15/2017']) AS [Count Of between (1/1/2017 AND 1/15/2017)]
    ,SUM([Count Of between '1/16/2017' AND '1/31/2017']) AS [Count Of between (1/16/2017     AND 1/31/2017)]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(Product) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY Product
            ) AS [Count Of between '1/1/2017' AND '1/15/2017']
        ,ISNULL(NULL, '') AS [Count Of between '1/16/2017' AND '1/31/2017']
    FROM cte
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '1/1/2017'
            AND '1/15/2017'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ISNULL(NULL, '')
        ,COUNT(Product) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY Product
            ) AS [Count Of between '1/16/2017' AND '1/31/2017']
    FROM cte
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '1/16/2017'
            AND '1/31/2017'
    ) Dt
```

OutPut

```
  Count Of between (1/1/2017 AND 1/15/2017) |   Count Of between (1/16/2017  AND 1/31/2017)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    5                                             2
```